# Background color won't apply to all of the div

Tags: css

I'm pretty sure the problem must lie in my CSS. I'm pretty sure the HTML is fine.  If I put height 100% it works in the .info but I don't want to do that.

```
.info {
    width:820px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
}

.info img { 
    float:left;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-left:5px;
}

.info article   {
    padding-left:5px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-indent:15px;
    width:600px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear floats..The easy way is to add `overflow: hidden` in `.info`

Or add the `class="cf"` in `.info`

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
   display: table;
   content: "";
}

.cf:after {
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Awesome that worked!  But I was wondering how come when I put float:left instead it didn't center it the margin:auto no longer worked?  By the way you're a genius and thank you!!!

Comment: It is floating left..why should you float it left and then center it? :) In your case, maybe you don't have to add float: left to img, just display: inline-block to article. It should work too. Img is already inline-block.

Comment: First time encountering inline-block what is it?  It's working but I don't know why..

Comment: @user3143131 http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/ Would be nice if you upvoted. ;)

Comment: I want to but my rep isn't high enough

Comment: Sorry I would if I could!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.info {
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this

```
.info {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting downvote. He says he does not have a height on the div, how should it with floats inside?

Comment: Sure, it will work the same as if you float: left too. But it's not correct..why should you do it inline-block, just to clear floats, just because it works?

Comment: @Naele Why should...arrgh, let me specify floats: They are for making text float around other elements. So why should you use floats out of the expected reason and then do something which builds on that misbehaviour and even makes it more wrong, if the solution is `inline-block`?

Comment: Read my answer.. i also mentioned that he doesn't need float-left, inline-block should work too. But for the article so as to float it next to the image , not .info. Info shouldn't be inline-block..

Comment: @Naele Ok, then just give me a reference for: "Img is already `inline-block`". Btw: The question was to give the div a height.